# How to do 'git add *' with libgit2sharp?

Tags: .net, git, libgit2sharp

I have an external process that applies changes to files part of a local Git repository initially cloned through libgit2sharp. I would like to perform - through libgit2sharp - the equivalent of the command `git add *`, followed by `git commit -m "Hello World"`. The documentation of the `Repository` class is thin on this.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In 2020 the code structure has been changed. Now its like==>

```
Commands.Stage(repo, "*");
```

Answer (score 5):

To simulate `git add *`, you can use:

```
 repo.Index.Stage("*");
```

Then, in order to create a commit, you can use the `repo.Commit(string, Signature, Signature)` method, which will commit all changes staged in the index.

For more information about the Commit feature, you can also rely on the [CommitFixture](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/CommitFixture.cs) tests (look for the `AddCommitToRepo` private method).

Comment: I *do* agree that the xml doc is pretty thin about this. Would you feel like sending a pull request to improve this? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To stage all my changes, I had to use:
repo.Stage(*);

Comment: Looks more like comment than answer